# New to javascript: whats wrong with my mobile detection code?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, mobile, detection

Here is EVERYTHING from my .js file :

```
function isMobile() {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};
```

Additionally, in my html, I have the following if else statements and included ONLY the following in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="function.js" ></script>
```

The if else in my html is as follows:

```
<!--Check if isMobile for video load-->
<script>
if (isMobile.any()) {
<p>
  <center>
    <div max-width="90%">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <h2>Shortest Job First Simulation in C++</h2></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <center>
              <iframe width="315" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HNTsNpiMIX8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </center>
</p>
} else {
<p>
  <center>
    <div max-width="90%">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <h2>Shortest Job First Simulation in C++</h2></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <center>
              <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HNTsNpiMIX8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </center>
</p>
} 
</script>
```

Now, I am a beginner. Can anyone tell me what might be wrong here? This is literally all the javascript related-ANYTHING in my code. Therefore if you know javascript, it might be obvious to you that something is missing, but don't assume that I have it and simply didn't add it to the post, because I don't. Like I said, this is literally everything. But neither of the videos load.
Any help?

Comment: You have never told what problem you are facing in the code

Comment: You should begin by closing your script tag. Also please say exactly what problem you are facing

Comment: Your code is syntactically erroneous. What does the console tell you?

Comment: Sorry, the issue is that it does not display either of the videos. And yup. I forgot to close the script tag. I just updated that though and unfortunately, its still not working.

Comment: You would need to share your complete code, as of now it is unclear how you're "loading" the video. Also please edit your post with the closed script tag.

Comment: Alrighty. I have included everything from the if else, if that helps. Any ideas what might be the issue?

Comment: Yes, the issue is that you are putting html markup (ie not javascript) inside your script tag. You can use [jQuery append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to do this, or [innerHtml in plain javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Comment: I'm still very new to jQuery as well. Can you elaborate on how I would do this syntactically?

Comment: does that answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are adding HTML markup inside your script tag, which should contain valid javascript.

I suggest using [jQuery append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) for this.

First, create a container element that will contain the HTML that you want to add, and give it an ID:

```
<div id="video-container"></div>
```

Then in your script tag, use the following syntax:

```
var small_video = "" // your html here in string form
var big_video = ""   // html for big video

if( isMobile.any() ){

    $("#video-container").append(small_video);

} else {

    $("#video-container").append(big_video);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for assisting. I attempted this formatting, but unfortunately it did not work either.

Answer (score -1):

Your JS is completely wrong syntactically

1. you have to *return* an object. (alternatively you can get rid of the function and make it as a POJO)

   ```
   function isMobile() {
     return {
       Android: function() {
         return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
       },
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. you have to *call* the function to get the object

   ```
   if (isMobile().any()) {
     // ...
   } else {
     //...
   }
   ```
3. change only width and height of iframe with JS

   ```
   <iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HNTsNpiMIX8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   <script>
   if (isMobile().any()) {
     var vid = document.getElementById('video');
     vid.height = 150;
     vid.width = 350;
   }
   </script>
   ```

BTW, welcome to SO

Comment: Hello, thank you for assisting. However I am very new to javascript/ web design. I normally only code in C++/ C#/ assembly. I followed your instructions but it unfortunately niether of the videos display. Also, if I may ask to verify, the only tags I would need in the header are <script type ="text/javascript"> correct?